# Is there a algorithm for Max Cut on a Planar Directed Graph (MAX DIRECTED CUT ALGORITHM)?

Tags: ds.algorithms

Max Cut on a Undirected Graph has many algorithms when the Undirected Graph is Planar. 
I have been wondering though if one could generalise this to Directed Planar Graphs?

Comment: What does max cut on a directed graph mean?

Comment: @Jelani: Exactly what you would think - only edges crossing in one direction counts towards the size.

Comment: The usual terminology is MAX DICUT.